# iPhone CAAnimations pause and resume

Tags: iphone, core-animation, cabasicanimation

Is it possible to **pause** / **resume** / **stop** `CAAnimation`, at any given time when animation is in progress?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929974/is-there-an-way-to-pause-an-core-animation-and-resume-it-at-some-time-later

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to pause a CABasicAnimation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306870/is-there-a-way-to-pause-a-cabasicanimation)

Comment: @Vladimir - Actually that question is a duplicate of this one. However this one is a duplicate of the question that Brad Larson mentioned.

Comment: Have a look at this (but how accurate works depends on device)
[Look at this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306870/is-there-a-way-to-pause-a-cabasicanimation