# How to pause and resume UIView Animation?

Tags: iphone, uiviewanimation

I have a UIView with several UILabels that is animating from top to bottom and vice versa. A sort of Autoque let's say :) I use 2 functions:

```
-(void)goUp 
-(void)goDown
```

Those functions start a UIView animation to the required position.They both have an *AnimationDidStopSelector* defined that calls the other function at the end. This all works smoothly.

When touching the screen, using touchesBegan, I would like to pause the current animation and change the vertical position of the UIView using touchesMoved event. In touchesEnded I want to resume the animation to the required end position.

What would be the proper way to do so?

Thomas

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104487/how-to-pause-and-resume-uiview-animation-without-block-animation is how i found it best to work.

Answer (score 7):

I've created a category on UIView to pause and stop animations:

```
@interface UIView (AnimationsHandler)

- (void)pauseAnimations;
- (void)resumeAnimations;

@end

@implementation UIView (AnimationsHandler)
- (void)pauseAnimations
{
    CFTimeInterval paused_time = [self.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    self.layer.speed = 0.0;
    self.layer.timeOffset = paused_time;
}

- (void)resumeAnimations
{
    CFTimeInterval paused_time = [self.layer timeOffset];
    self.layer.speed = 1.0f;
    self.layer.timeOffset = 0.0f;
    self.layer.beginTime = 0.0f;
    CFTimeInterval time_since_pause = [self.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - paused_time;
    self.layer.beginTime = time_since_pause;
}
```

Comment: suggest to check in resumeAnimations if paused_time == 0 to make sure we paused it before

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to play well with UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can still pause the `UIView` animations based on the answer to the question that Vladimir linked to as it pause my `CABasicAnimations` as well as my `UIView` animations after I had implemented all my animations as `CABasicaAnimations` and then added some `UIView` animations afterwards that I had thought wouldn't be paused, but they didn't work either. [This is the relevant link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1673/_index.html).

I wanted to pause my whole view so I passed `self.view.layer` as the layer to be paused. But for those who don't know about `CALayer`'s, pass in the `view.layer` that you want paused. Each `UIView` has a `CALayer`, so just pass in the upmost `view.layer` that is relevant for you. In the case of Thomas, based on your own answer, it would seem that you would want to pass in `self.containerView.layer` to be paused.

The reason that this works is because `UIView` animations are simply a layer on top of Core Animation. At least that's my understanding.

Hope this helps future people wondering how to pause animations.

Answer (score 2):

Vladimir, the question about CAAnimations make sense.. but I found a way to 'pause' so I could keep using UIView animations:

```
CALayer *pLayer = [self.containerView.layer presentationLayer];
CGRect frameStop = pLayer.frame;
pausedX = frameStop.origin.x;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.01];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];     
// set view properties

frameStop.origin.x = pausedX;
self.containerView.frame = frameStop;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

What I'm doing here is using the presentationLayer to find out current x value of the animated view. After that I execute a new animation which overwrites the original animation. Make sure to setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentstate:YES for this. This cancels the original animation and puts the animated view not to it's destination position (which it does automatically ) but at the current position of the animation proces..

Hope this helps others too! :)

Comment: If you define pausedX as an int, it gets silently cast to a CGFloat. frameStop is a CGRect, which is a struct made of a CGSize and a CGPoint. The origin point is a struct made of two CGFloats.

Comment: How can you do this if you're animating a transform rather than a frame?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is possible with UIView's directly but you definitely can do that animating view's CALayers instead. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306870/is-there-a-way-to-pause-a-cabasicanimation) about pausing and resuming of CAAnimations.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you.

```
- (void)goUP{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [self.layer timeOffset];
    self.layer.speed = 1.0;
    self.layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
    self.layer.beginTime = 0.0;
    CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [self.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
    self.layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}

- (void)goDown{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [self.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    self.layer.speed = 0.0;
    self.layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}
```

When you call the Layer animate, it will effect all layer tree and submode layer animate.