# Resume UIView animation when app is resumed

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiviewanimation

I have a looping animation like this:

```
       UIView.Animate(50, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, () => { 
            bgBackground.Frame = new RectangleF(new PointF(-496, bgBackground.Frame.Y), bgBackground.Frame.Size);
        }, () => {});
```

but when the app goes to background and the animation is not running.

I've listened for the event when the app comes to foreground but I can't figure out how to restart the animation.

I have another looping animation using CABasicAnimation and that one is still running when resuming the app so can't I use UIView based animations for looping animations?

Other similar questions have just provided CALayer animations as the solution:

- [How to pause and resume UIView Animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211065/how-to-pause-and-resume-uiview-animation)
- [How to pause and resume UIView Animation (without Block Animation)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104487/how-to-pause-and-resume-uiview-animation-without-block-animation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote to use CABasicAnimation and then everything works great.

```
CABasicAnimation animSc;
animSc = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("transform.translation.x");
animSc.From = NSNumber.FromFloat(0.0f);
animSc.To = NSNumber.FromFloat(-496.0f);
animSc.Duration = 50.0f;
animSc.RepeatCount = INFITE_NUMBER;
bgView.Layer.AddAnimation(animSc, "bg_anim");
```

And then I just call the above code when the view appears and everything starts animating again.