# Start and stop animation with CABasicAnimation iphone

Tags: iphone, animation, cabasicanimation

I want to use animation for image, start on button clicked and stop after 5 seconds.I use this code.

```
-(IBAction) btnClicked
{   
    CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
    fullRotation.duration = 6;
    fullRotation.repeatCount = 1e100f;
    fullRotation.delegate = self;
    [imgView.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
    [imgView.layer setSpeed:3.0];
}
```

with this code animation is started but i don't know how to stop this animation after 5 seconds.

Comment: Goto This Link It's Have Your Perfect Solution.
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306870/is-there-a-way-to-pause-a-cabasicanimation)

Answer (score 1):

Don't even deal with `CoreAnimation`. I think this can be do this with `UIView` animations, which are easier to program. Look at `UIView` documentation and try the block animations (assuming iOS 4.0. if not, use older style).

Look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1) for the docs on `UIView` animations.  Set the `transform` property to do the rotation using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`.

Here is a `UIView` based animated rotation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *viewToAnimate = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)] autorelease];
    viewToAnimate.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:viewToAnimate];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
        viewToAnimate.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Davidneiss.But I want this animation with clockwise and anti-clockwise will it be possible with UIView animation ?