# MBProgressHud with gif image

Tags: ios, objective-c, animated-gif, mbprogresshud

Can I use gif image instead of default loading indicator? I am using this code so far but not getting any result. Can anyone suggest what is wrong in this code?

```
#import "UIImage+GIF.h"
-(void) showLoadingHUD:(NSString *)title
{
    [self hideLoadingHUD];
    if(!HUD){
        HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.window animated:YES];
    }
    [HUD setColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UIImageView *imageViewAnimatedGif = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    imageViewAnimatedGif.image= [UIImage sd_animatedGIFNamed:@"martini_glass"];

    HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageViewAnimatedGif.image];
    CABasicAnimation *rotation;
    rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    rotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(2 * M_PI)];
    rotation.duration = 0.7f; // Speed
    rotation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF; // Repeat forever. Can be a finite number.
    [HUD.customView.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"Spin"];
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
    [HUD show:YES];
}
```

Comment: check this : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/gifprogresshud

Comment: @AntonyRaphel checked this. I want to know can i implement this using MBProgressHUD.

Comment: code added as ans

Comment: @AntonyRaphel Thanks.. It works!!!!!

Comment: you are welcome!!

Comment: one line added in code. check on updated code for work fine. `rotation.removedOnCompletion = false;`

Comment: @AntonyRaphel OK.. !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use latest libraries of [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) and [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for **"UIImage+GIF.h"** and it is working fine

```
-(void) showLoadingHUD:(NSString *)title {

    [HUD hideAnimated:true];
    HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    HUD.label.text = title;
    HUD.bezelView.color = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIImageView *imageViewAnimatedGif = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

    //The key here is to save the GIF file or URL download directly into a NSData instead of making it a UIImage. Bypassing UIImage will let the GIF file keep the animation.
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"loader" ofType: @"gif"];
    NSData *gifData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
    imageViewAnimatedGif.image = [UIImage sd_animatedGIFWithData:gifData];

    HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageViewAnimatedGif.image];
    CABasicAnimation *rotation;
    rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    rotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(2 * M_PI)];
    rotation.duration = 0.7f; // Speed
    rotation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF; // Repeat forever. Can be a finite number.
    rotation.removedOnCompletion = false;
    [HUD.customView.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"Spin"];
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
    HUD.contentColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [HUD showAnimated:YES];
}
```

sample loader .gif image: 
[image: loader]

Comment: Is there any way to set the size of the .gif to 100*100 through code?

Comment: @Mamta set the size for this var `imageViewAnimatedGif`

Comment: Any swift version for this answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a UIImageView that animates a set of images, and then set the customView property of your MBProgressHUD to be that UIImageView.

Here's a tutorial about creating a UIImageView that animates the images: Create Custom Activity Indicator for your iOS App

[link to the tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20120730005439/http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=336)

Hope it help...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use gif images instead of default loading...

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.label.text = @"loading…";
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"toast_loading"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
CABasicAnimation *anima = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
anima.toValue = http://www.cnblogs.com/Apologize/p/@(M_PI*2);
anima.duration = 1.0f;
anima.repeatCount = 10;
[imgView.layer addAnimation:anima forKey:nil];
hud.customView = imgView;

hud.bezelView.color = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:1];
// text color
hud.contentColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
hud.animationType = MBProgressHUDAnimationFade;
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3
I have created two functions in Swift. File name is Globle.Swift. After Create a UIApplication.Swift file and put the following extension for getting topViewController

public extension UIApplication {

class func topViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {

```
    if let nav = viewController as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tab = viewController as? UITabBarController {
        if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = viewController?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(presented)
    }
    if let slide = viewController as? SlideMenuController {
        return topViewController(slide.mainViewController)
    }
    return viewController
}
```

}

```
open class func showLoadingSpinner(_ message: String? = "", sender: UIView? = UIApplication.topViewController()?.view) -> Void {
    let  HUD = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: sender!, animated: true)
    HUD.label.text = message
    HUD.bezelView.color = UIColor.clear
    let imageViewAnimatedGif = UIImageView()
    //The key here is to save the GIF file or URL download directly into a NSData instead of making it a UIImage. Bypassing UIImage will let the GIF file keep the animation.
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "loader", ofType: "gif")
    let gifData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath ?? "") as Data?
    imageViewAnimatedGif.image = UIImage.sd_animatedGIF(with: gifData)
    HUD.customView = UIImageView(image: imageViewAnimatedGif.image)
    var rotation: CABasicAnimation?
    rotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotation?.fromValue = nil
// If you want to rotate Gif Image Uncomment 
  //  rotation?.toValue = CGFloat.pi * 2
    rotation?.duration = 0.7
    rotation?.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    HUD.customView?.layer.add(rotation!, forKey: "Spin")
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.customView
   // Change hud bezelview Color and blurr effect
    HUD.bezelView.color = UIColor.clear
    HUD.bezelView.tintColor = UIColor.clear
    HUD.bezelView.style = .solidColor
    HUD.bezelView.blurEffectStyle = .dark
    // Speed
    rotation?.repeatCount = .infinity
    HUD.show(animated: true)

}

open class func dismissLoadingSpinner(_ sender: UIView? = UIApplication.topViewController()?.view) -> Void {
    MBProgressHUD.hide(for: sender!, animated: true)
}


// Call Function from your viewController to Show 
Global.showLoadingSpinner(sender: self.view)
// Call Function from your view controller to Hide
Global.dismissLoadingSpinner(self.view)
```

Comment: I am getting error, Type 'UIApplication' has no member 'topViewController'. Can you please help?

Comment: @Nij Sorry I did not add topViewController Function which is hold by UIApplication Extension. Just Add it i Have Edited my post see again.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply. Will get it by AppDelegate.window