# Incorrect UIViewPropertyAnimator behaviour when called recursively and app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, recursion, cabasicanimation, uiviewpropertyanimator

I have created a very simple class (SpinningCircleView) of type UIView that performs a spinning circle animation forever. I want to call this class from my ViewController to display the spinning circle animation on the screen. While the animation works great, I am observing incorrect behavior when the app is put in the background. Here is what the spinning circle animation looks like:

[image: Spinning circle animation captured on Simulator]

To create the spinning circle, I am using two separate UIViewPropertyAnimator, one to rotate the circle by 180 degrees (i.e. Pi) and the other to complete to 360 (i.e. 0 degrees). In the completion block of the second animator, I am then recursively calling the startSpinningCircleAnimation() function. I created a counter to track the number of times the startSpinningCircleAnimation() is called (i.e. the number of times the circle has rotated). While the app is active (in the foreground), the counter increments as expected and  I can see the output in my Xcode terminal window:

```
Starting animation
1: + START Spinning Circle Animation
2: + START Spinning Circle Animation -> recursive call
3: + START Spinning Circle Animation -> recursive call
4: + START Spinning Circle Animation -> recursive call
```

The **problem** or incorrect behavior happens is when I put the app into the background...all of a sudden I am seeing several hundred "+ START Spinning Circle Animation -> recursive call" in my terminal. When the app comes back to the foreground, the counter and terminal output resume normal increments of the counter.

Why are several hundred calls being made to the startSpinningCircleAnimation() function when the app is put in the background? How can I correctly pause the animation and resume the animation as the app is moved between background and foreground? I have scoured through various posts but I can't figure out the solution.

Please help!!

Here is my SpinningCircleView class:

```
import UIKit

class SpinningCircleView: UIView
{
    
    private lazy var spinningCircle = CAShapeLayer()
    private lazy var animator1 = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .linear, animations: nil)
    private lazy var animator2 = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .linear, animations: nil)
    public var counter = 0
    
    override init (frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func configure()
    {
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        let rect = self.bounds
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
        spinningCircle.path = circularPath.cgPath
        spinningCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        spinningCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.systemRed.cgColor
        spinningCircle.lineWidth = 10
        spinningCircle.strokeEnd = 0.25
        spinningCircle.lineCap = .round
        self.layer.addSublayer(spinningCircle)
    }
    
    func startSpinningCircleAnimation()
    {
        counter += 1
        
        let criteria1 = animator1.state == .active && !animator1.isRunning
        let criteria2 = animator2.state == .active && !animator2.isRunning
        let criteria3 = animator1.state == .inactive && animator2.state == .inactive
        let criteria4 = (animator1.state == .inactive && animator2.state.rawValue == 5) || (animator2.state == .inactive && animator1.state.rawValue == 5)
        
        if (criteria1)
        {
            // Since animator1 is Paused, we will resume the animation
            print("\(self.counter): ~ RESUME Spinning Circle Animation")
            animator1.startAnimation()
        } else if (criteria2)
        {
            // Since animator2 is Paused, we will resume the animation
            print("\(self.counter): ~ RESUME Spinning Circle Animation")
            animator2.startAnimation()
        } else if (criteria3 || criteria4)
        {
            
            if (criteria3)
            {
                print("\(self.counter): + START Spinning Circle Animation")
            } else if (criteria4)
            {
                print("\(self.counter): + START Spinning Circle Animation -> recursive call")
            }
            
            animator1.addAnimations
            {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
            }
            
            animator1.addCompletion
            {   _ in
                
                self.animator2.addAnimations
                {
                    self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
                }
                
                self.animator2.addCompletion
                { _ in
                    // Recursively call this start spinning
                    self.startSpinningCircleAnimation()
                }
                
                self.animator2.startAnimation()
            }
            
            animator1.startAnimation()
        } else
        {
            print("\(self.counter): >>>>>>>>> HERE <<<<<<<<<<<  \(self.animator1.state) \(self.animator1.isRunning) \(self.animator2.state) \(self.animator2.isRunning)")
        }
        
    }
    
    
    func stopSpinningCircleAnimation()
    {
        print("\(self.counter): - STOP Spinning Circle Animation Begin: \(self.animator1.state) \(self.animator1.isRunning) \(self.animator2.state) \(self.animator2.isRunning)")
        
        if (self.animator1.isRunning)
        {
            self.animator1.pauseAnimation()
        } else if (self.animator2.isRunning)
        {
            self.animator2.pauseAnimation()
        }
        
        print("\(self.counter): - STOP Spinning Circle Animation End: \(self.animator1.state) \(self.animator1.isRunning) \(self.animator2.state) \(self.animator2.isRunning)")
    }

}
```

Here is my ViewController which sets up an instance of the SpinningCircleView and starts animating:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{

    private lazy var spinningCircleView = SpinningCircleView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Setup the spinning circle and display the animation to the screen
        spinningCircleView.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x - 50, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
        spinningCircleView.tag = 100
        view.addSubview(spinningCircleView)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        print("Starting animation")
        spinningCircleView.startSpinningCircleAnimation()
    }
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        print("Pausing animation")
        spinningCircleView.stopSpinningCircleAnimation()
    }

}
```

Comment: Summary of solution: I replaced the animation methodology from using  "UIViewPropertyAnimator" and instead to using "CABasicAnimation". Also, using 'recursion' to achieve the infinite spinning circle was NOT good idea in my case. Thanks to @bewithyou for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer each of your question

> Why are several hundred calls being made to the startSpinningCircleAnimation() function when the app is put in the background?

I think because every time you called `startSpinningCircleAnimation()` in completion and you check `state` which is inactive, ... of animation before. The things which is wrong here maybe is in the logic of check state in your recursion.

I will not deep dive into your code to find the wrong one. But I will refactor your `SpinningCircleView`

First of all, don't need to use two `UIViewPropertyAnimator` just for making the view rotate continuously. Simple logic here is just make the view to be rotate and repeat it.

```swift
let rotation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
rotation.toValue = Double.pi * 2
rotation.duration = 1
rotation.isCumulative = true
rotation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
rotation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
self.layer.add(rotation, forKey: "rotateInfinityAnimation")
```

And for your second question

> How can I correctly pause the animation and resume the animation as the app is moved between background and foreground?

You just need to catch the notification where your app will enter foreground or background from `NotificationCenter`.

```swift
private func addNotification() {
    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appEnterForground), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}
```

For stop and resume animation, you just need to know that when animation happens the layer of the view is the one which occurs the animation. So you just need to add function to stop and resume on the layer of the view. Then every time you want to pause or resume just call from `view.layer.resume()` or `view.layer.stop()`

```swift
extension CALayer {
    func pause() {
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = self.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
        self.speed = 0.0
        self.timeOffset = pausedTime
    }

    func resume() {
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = self.timeOffset
        self.speed = 1.0
        self.timeOffset = 0.0
        self.beginTime = 0.0
        let timeSincePause: CFTimeInterval = self.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
        self.beginTime = timeSincePause
    }
}
```

Your `SpinningCircleView` will be like this

```swift
class SpinningCircleView: UIView {
    private lazy var spinningCircle = CAShapeLayer()
    private var didStopAnimation = false
    
    override init (frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func configure()
    {
        didStopAnimation = false
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        let rect = self.bounds
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
        spinningCircle.path = circularPath.cgPath
        spinningCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        spinningCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.systemRed.cgColor
        spinningCircle.lineWidth = 10
        spinningCircle.strokeEnd = 0.25
        spinningCircle.lineCap = .round
        self.layer.addSublayer(spinningCircle)
        self.addNotification()
    }
    
    private func addNotification() {
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func appEnterForeground() {
        if didStopAnimation {
            return
        }
        
        self.layer.resume()
    }
    
    @objc func appMovedToBackground() {
        if didStopAnimation {
            return
        }
        
        self.layer.pause()
    }
        
    func startSpinningCircleAnimation() {
        if didStopAnimation {
            return
        }
        
        let rotation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        rotation.toValue = Double.pi * 2
        rotation.duration = 1
        rotation.isCumulative = true
        rotation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        rotation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        self.layer.add(rotation, forKey: "rotateInfinityAnimation")
    }
    
    
    func stopSpinningCircleAnimation() {
        didStopAnimation = true
        self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Yes, the refactored code is much cleaner. However, even using your refactored version of SpinningCirlceView (+ extension CALayer) the original issue I reported here is present. I only added a counter variable to your code which is incremented and printed to the screen at the very beginning of startSpinningCircleAnimation() - when the app moves to the background, there are several print statements flooded to the Xcode Console. Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: Dear @atrdeveloper, that's because of the recursion. I've refactored using method animation without recursion. Check again

Comment: Appreciate the updated code @bewithyou. This works great if triggering the UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, but doesn't work when the App is completely in the background (i.e. triggering a UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification). Re-entering the app from Home screen displays stuck/frozen circle...actually it never even starts/resumes the animation. Do you know why this is happening? Ultimately this is the real case for my app (the spinning circle should resume spinning after the user comes back to the app following a UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification). Thoughts?

Comment: Dear @atrdeveloper, you just need to add more notification to catch from ``NotificationCenter`` or catch to remove or start again from your ``ViewController``. There are some ways to catch the exceptions I just give you know one of them and remove the recursion.

Comment: I have added the required notification. What i am trying to say is that the self.layer.resume() function is not working when the app enters the foreground (i.e. UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification) **after** the app is completely in the background (i.e. UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification). Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Good news...after doing some additional Googling, I found a solution to the CABasicAnimation implementation which solves the latest issue I am referring to in my previous comment. The solution is to set 'rotation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false' as per the following example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10098800/13558133. Now everything works as expected! Thanks for all your help again :)