# CABasicAnimation current elapsed time

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-animation

I just rewrote quite a big animation from a dumb while loop (firing drawRect: x times) and this is the last thing that I just can't figure out..

How can I get the current elapsed time of my animation? I know how to get the current CFTimeInterval ([Is there a way to pause a CABasicAnimation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306870/is-there-a-way-to-pause-a-cabasicanimation)):

```
CFTimeInterval currentTime = [self.multiplierLayer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
```

But how can I use this to calculate the current elapsed time from the moment my animation started? It seems that beginTime is always 0.0, do I have to set that the moment my animation starts and then extract the currentTime from the beginTime?

I'm sorry if it's something simple that I'm overlooking, I just started using Core Animation yesterday. :)

**Edit:**
Setting beginTime is **not** the way to do it, really at a loss here.

Comment: Why can't you simply record the current time when the animation started (which you know as you had to start it)?

Comment: or be the delegate and check in `animationDidStart:`

Comment: So combined; record the current time inside `animationDidStart:`. Yes that would work nice for a single animation, but what about multiple animations? Just track them all? It would be a shame if there is no other way to get the elapsed time from an animation.

Comment: You record the value **in** the CALayer itself using a `NSNumber` object and `setValue:forKey:`.

Comment: Ah! I need to go out for a bit now, will try this when I get back. When it works (it will), could you submit it as the answer so I can check it?

Comment: Totally forgot to come back here, sorry. Could you add your answer as an answer so I can give you the credits? I got it to work :)

Answer (score 10):

A possibly easier way to do what you want is when you create your CABasicAnimation explicitly set the starting time, like:

```
basicAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
```

Later on you can figure out how much time has elapsed with:

```
CFTimeInterval elapsedTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - basicAnimation.beginTime;
```

And get the percentage through with:

```
progress = elapsedTime / basicAnimation.duration;
```

(The code will be slightly more complex if you have a timeOffset or something like that.)