# CABasicAnimation progress with variable speed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I need to calculate the progress of a CABasicAnimation at a time T in order to update a progress view.

When the progress is linear, I simply calculate the elapsed time at each time (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20993376/2268168).

The thing is, the animation is not linear, the speed is variable.

Speed up

```
mylayer.timeOffset = [mylayer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
mylayer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
mylayer.speed=2;
speed = 2;
```

Slow down

```
mylayer.timeOffset = [mylayer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
mylayer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
mylayer.speed=0.5;
speed = 0.5;
```

How can I calculate the progress of the animation taking into account the variable speed ?

I tried this, but it seems to work only when the speed increases once.

```
CFTimeInterval elapsedTime = (CACurrentMediaTime() - animation.beginTime);

CFTimeInterval remainingTime = (totalDuration - elapsedTime)/speed;
speed = 1;
totalDuration = remainingTime+elapsedTime;

float progress = (totalDuration-remainingTime)/totalDuration;
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at the technique suggested by this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19024971/294949.  The clever-seeming idea is to add a layer to animate a rect, and use the size of that rect as a measure of progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @danh for pointing me to this answer [Core animation progress callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827973/core-animation-progress-callback/19024971#19024971).

It helped me.

I added the subclassed CALayer, animated it the same way I animated my layer (with the same speed variations). That way, I can get the progress of the main animation.