# Stopping CAAnimation to add another CAAnimation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, calayer, caanimation

I have a rotating circle shape with 5 subviews and I am animating changes to its fillcolor to match the subview that is currently on top. So when I have to change the color I remove animations from that layer and then add the new one like this:

```
[self.dynamicColorCircleLayer removeAllAnimations]; //checked - doesn't matter if line is added or not
        switch (index) {
            case 0: {
                CABasicAnimation *fillColorAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"fillColor"];
                fillColorAnimation.duration = 2;
                //fillColorAnimation.fromValue = (id)self.dynamicColorCircleLayer.fillColor;
                fillColorAnimation.toValue = (id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
                fillColorAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
                fillColorAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
                fillColorAnimation.delegate = self;
                [self.dynamicColorCircleLayer addAnimation:fillColorAnimation forKey:@"fillColor"];
```

etc.

And the delegate method:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag {
    self.dynamicColorCircleLayer.fillColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)(((CABasicAnimation*)theAnimation).toValue);
}
```

However when one animation hasn't ended and I have to start another, the new one immediately ends.
Fore example: I am animating color change from red to blue, I'm in the middle of animation and I have to animate color change to green. The animation isn't showing, circle just immediately changes color to green.
If I remove code from animationDidStop(...), I will get an animation to green, but every animation will start from the default (red) color.

What is the right way to interrupt animation with another animation? Also, is it even possible to make the new animation start from the color it had at the moment when I removed the older animation? (In the example above, it would be animating color change to green from a color between red and blue)

Answer (score 1):

Refer this question:

[Is there a way to pause a CABasicAnimation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306870/is-there-a-way-to-pause-a-cabasicanimation)

Here first answer explains how to pause existing animation and the second answer says how to stop the same.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't fix my problem, but +1 for useful information. I found another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this, however I still have no idea how to start the next animation from the color at which the previous one was stopped. Here it is in case anyone will need it:

```
CABasicAnimation *currentAnimation = (CABasicAnimation*)[self.dynamicColorCircleLayer animationForKey:@"fillColor"];
if (currentAnimation != nil) {
    self.dynamicColorCircleLayer.fillColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)(currentAnimation.toValue);
}
switch (index) {
    case 0: {
        CABasicAnimation *fillColorAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"fillColor"];
        fillColorAnimation.duration = 2.5f;
        fillColorAnimation.toValue = (id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
        fillColorAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        fillColorAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        fillColorAnimation.delegate = self;
        [self.dynamicColorCircleLayer addAnimation:fillColorAnimation forKey:@"fillColor"];

        break;
    } (...)
```

And in the delegate method:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag {
    if (flag) {
        self.dynamicColorCircleLayer.fillColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)(((CABasicAnimation*)theAnimation).toValue);
    }
}
```

Now, when i.e. animation that changes color to green is either succesfully finished or interrupted early, fillcolor will just change to green and begin next animation if needed.