# Show part of a circle

Tags: swift

i want to display an arbitray part of a circle.
I know how to get a round View using `layer.cornerRadius` now i want to see only a part of that circle(for any given radiant value). It would be ok, if the rest of it would be simply hidden beneath something white.
Any ideas, how to achieve that?

edit:
i have written a class for my View:

```
class Circle:UIView {
var rad = 0

    let t = CGFloat(3.0)

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        let r = self.frame.width / CGFloat(2)
        let center = CGPoint(x: r, y: r)
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: t, y: r))

        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: r))

        path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: CGFloat(r), startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi+rad), clockwise: true)

        let pos = path.currentPoint
        let dx = r - pos.x
        let dy = r - pos.y
        let d = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
        let p = t / d
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: pos.x + p * dx, y: pos.y + p * dy))
        path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: r-t, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi+rad), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), clockwise: false)


        UIColor(named: "red")?.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }
}

public func setRad(perc:Double) {
    rad = Double.pi * 2 * perc

}
```

in my view controller i call

```
    circleView.layer.cornerRadius = circleView.frame.size.width / 2
    circleView.clipsToBounds = true
    circleView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    circleView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor

    circleView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    circleView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    circleView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    circleView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    circleView.layer.masksToBounds = false

    circleView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onTap)))
```

now i get the full square View with a black circle from the corner and the red arc that i draw. If necessary i will post a picture tomorrow

Comment: UIBezierPath is your helper here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857312/how-do-i-apply-an-animation-around-a-button

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to draw a `UIBezierPath`.

If you just want an arc, you can call the `init(arcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:)` initializer. Remember to specify the start and end angles in radians!

[image]

After that, you can set the stroke color and call `stroke`

If you want a sector of a circle, you can create a `UIBezierPath` with the parameterless initializer, then `move(to:)` the center of the circle, and then `addLine(to:)` the start of the arc. You can probably calculate where this point is with a bit of trigonometry. After that, call `addArc` like I described above, then `addLine(to:)` the point where you started. After that, you can `fill` the path.

Comment: ok i get the arc drawn, but now i can see the original border in addition to the border, that i get by setting cornerRadius

Comment: @Ginso then don’t  set the corner radius or the border and draw the view you want entirely in `draw(_:)`.

Comment: but even if i don't call the super.draw and use UIBezierPath ro fill the entire frame with clear color, i get a white View

Comment: What are you trying to draw exactly? Can you show a picture? @Ginso