# how to animate drawing of a circle and animate the erasing of the same circle in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uikit

This question is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37158551/8071224) answer for animating the drawing of a circle.

My question is how to erase the drawn circle by animating the erasing similar to the answer provided in the link above?

Comment: Do the same thing again, just reverse the direction of the animation and change stroke color to white.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thank you! that worked!