# how to pause imageView animation?

Tags: ios, swift

I use this code to create rotation animation for my imageView:

```
func rotate(imageView: UIImageView, aCircleTime: Double) { 
        
        let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotationAnimation.toValue = -Double.pi * 2 
        rotationAnimation.duration = aCircleTime
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
        imageView.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
```

But how to pause this animation?

Comment: `imageView.layer.speed=0` ?

Comment: @matt I have a rotation animation. And when I press the pause button my imageVIew should stop at the current rotation angle. And in your case, it just stops at the starting point.

Comment: @matt Isn't this community all about asking questions? To make it easier for others to search?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking me. This is an encyclopedia of question-answer topics. There are already question-answer topics on the thing you are having trouble with, so to get work done, look at those and you will see what to do.

Comment: I just did a search and one answer even links to an Apple document on this very topic: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1673/_index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to pause and resume CAAnimations, but it's fussy and a little confusing. Take a look at this project on Github:

https://github.com/DuncanMC/ClockWipeSwift.git

It uses an extension on CALayer:

```
//  Credit to Rand, from Stack Overflow, for the basis of this extension
//  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59079995/205185

import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

import Foundation

extension CALayer
{

    func isPaused() -> Bool {
        return speed == 0
    }

    private func internalPause(_ pause: Bool) {
        if pause {
            let pausedTime = convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
            speed = 0.0
            timeOffset = pausedTime
        } else {
            let pausedTime = timeOffset
            speed = 1.0
            timeOffset = 0.0
            beginTime = 0.0
            let timeSincePause = convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
            beginTime = timeSincePause
        }
    }


    func pauseAnimation(_ pause: Bool) {
        if pause != isPaused()  {
            internalPause(pause)
        }
    }

    func pauseOrResumeAnimation() {
        internalPause(isPaused())
    }
}
```

Pausing and resuming is much easier if you use UIView animation and UIViewPropertyAnimator. There are lots of tutorials that explain how to do it.

You can look at [**this project on Github**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/UIViewPropertyAnimator-test.git) that shows how to use `UIViewPropertyAnimator`.